Would this be a suitable setup or there are better ideas to build the drone power supply?
I am building a tethered drone used in washing houses and solar panels, most important aspect being the overall drone system weight.
The overall use would be washing up to 15M high with a drone (Phantom 3 or similar modified). Overall consumption is around 200 W.
Now, i aim at designing a system that is going to be able to provide 15A at 15V over a length of wire of 15-18 meters, 1 to 1.5 mm section, while powered from a 24V 20A AC-DC power supply.
The drone will not have an installed battery, will run only from the tethered source. (This would remove around 400G weight on takeoff to be used by the water supply hose).
I don't want to run higher voltage, either AC or DC due to safety reason in operation.
I explored sending AC-AC and using and bridge rectifier setup + voltage regulator on drone to provide the voltage, but i cant find and suitable 220-24 AC-AC transformer that can supply 15-20-30A.
The big problem is the power loss in the DC-DC cable portion from the ground power supply to the drone where the voltage will be dependent on the drawn current. AT 15A over the full length of the wire with 1.5mm section the voltage loss would be around 5V for a total of almost 100W power loss in the wire, leaving me with a 20V 15A power supply at the end of the wire.
I plan on building an array of 20 1A linear regulators so i can provide an steady 15V-15A power supply in the drone(I want to build it like this for weight reason, as the overall voltage regulator would weight at around 60G, air cooled).

As a home PV owner, wrestling with a hose-equipped brush of greater than 10 m handle length, I've pondered a ground powered/tethered UAV for panel cleaning purposes. I lack the technical acumen to bring such a project to fruition. I wish you the best of luck in solving these difficulties and hope to see it on the 'net in the future. This is one situation in which I'd like to see personal contact allowed, for future results monitoring and support.

you can look up current capacity vs wire cross section in standard tables found easily by search. Generally speaking, delivering the same power with more voltage and less current is preferable. Requires less copper, therefore lighter wires. 48V supply might be a nice level if you want to stay below the nominally 75V threshold of a "low voltage" device. Also at 200W, the disadvantages of a linear regulator would probably justify an alternative plus however much filtering is necessary
